# How to get a facebook user id from the login email address

Tags: facebook, facebook-graph-api, facebook-opengraph

Is there a way to get a user's facebook user id from their login email address?

I want an API call where I can provide `joe@example.com` and get facebook user id `342255534`.

I'll use that id to call `http://graph.facebook.com/342255534/picture?type=large`

The closest thing I've found is `https://graph.facebook.com/search?q=EMAILADDRESS&type=user&access_token=ACCESSTOKEN`, but that requires an access token, which I'm hoping to avoid.

I know this isn't how it's supposed to work, but is there a way to get a generic access token?

Comment: impossible even with an access_token. Facebook is very protective on emails. try getting friend_emails and you will see there is no such option

Comment: i'm not trying to get the email address out. i'm trying to provide an email address and get an id.

Comment: i understood that pal. i usually save the users facebook_id and email in the database so that it makes retrieval easier...

Comment: gotcha. thanks for your help :) i guess i'll have to see if i can convince folks to use something like gravatar.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use your own access_token for the application, and change it to a long-lived access token so you can make the API call in a cron. The only issue is that you will have to login to the app every so often to update the access token.

**UPDATE**: The User Search API is now deprecated, so you cannot search using email addresses. But name based searches still work.

Comment: Is that compliant with the ToS?

Comment: It's a bit of a grey area. But it should be acceptable as you are using access_tokens.

Comment: I'm also curious about it compliant with TOS. Has anyone got their app blocked for this yet?

Answer (score 0):

You can create an app and get an access token for that app. Instructions are here: https://developers.facebook.com/docs/authentication/applications/

Unfortunately, a search for a user_id by email only works with a user access token.

You don't need to be friends with a user to get their id by email address.